# Refreshing PHP Get method after pressing enter

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a website that takes certain data through the "GET" method, parses it within the script and echoes back out some numbers based on the results it finds in the database.

So http://XXX.XX.XXX/data.php?Numbers=1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

Displays: 6563

Now when I change one of the numbers or all the numbers being sent to the website directly in the url, it SHOULD change the value echoed back out HOWEVER this only happens if I hit refresh (CTRL-R) and Not when I hit enter. I need it to happen when I hit enter aka refresh without actually having to hit refresh

http://XXX.XX.XXX/data.php?Numbers=10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100 110 120

Displays: 6563 When it should display something else

If anyone knows the issue or what can be done to solve this, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: We cannot answer this without seeing your code. Does your script *receive* those changed numbers in `$_GET` (it should)?

Comment: Yes it does receive as it should

Answer (score 1):

First, you shouldn't have spaces in your URL like that. Take a look at [`urlencode`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php) and [`urldecode`<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Your specific problem (without seeing any code) seems to be the result of your browser caching the page results. The CTRL+R tells the browser, "I don't care what you have cached, get me a new copy".

To get around unwanted browser caching you can try using the `header` function **before** your script sends any output to the browser (if you don't you'll get an error message about headers already being sent) to tell the client not to cache the page:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Whether or not the browser obeys your command is entirely up to the browser's discretion (though it's supposed to).

Comment: Tried this but same problem... Pretty much think of it as a form where once you hit submit, the data displayed on the page it takes you doesnt refresh until the user actually hits refresh... Is there some way to refresh the connection on it its own

Comment: @Teddy13 You'll have to post some code for people to be able to accurately diagnose whatever the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you url encoding/decoding the data? It seems that you are not doing that. Check this: http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php

Comment: The browser does it automatically for me though? I feel the issue is still with the refresh because whenever I hit CTRL-R, I get the results I need but I need this to happen without hitting refresh

Comment: No it shouldn't encode things for you. Without knowing your setup or code we can only guess.

Comment: @alfa Yes, the browser *should* automatically URL encode illegal values in a URL.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your browser is caching the page, and only actually re-downloading it when you press refresh.

Try adding this to your script (before any output):

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Comment: Will give this a try now... either way thank you, will post results

Comment: Did not work, I still need to hit refresh/ change numbers to get a new echoed number